# Ethernet Thunderbolt on Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, windows, thunderbolt

So, I'm running a rMBP, and my BootCamp simply refuses to recognise my Ethernet. I can see it recognises the Thunderbolt converter, as there's an option to eject it under 'Safely eject hardware'. I'm rather bad with technical stuff, but I tried manually installing a driver or something like that (I found a solution here that seemed to work for people, but I couldn't figure it out for the life of me).. I haven't unplugged it since startup, so that's not the issue.

Comment: `I found a solution here that seemed to work for people...` Could you maybe link to that solution and explain what step you find difficult to understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the bootcamp driver to your win7 all necessary drivers are already installed but I´ve figured out that you have to reboot your windows if you connect the adapter to your mac. So the best solution is that you first connect the adapter to your mac and after that you should start/boot up your mac to windows.